# material-ui renderToStaticMarkup not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to render a material-ui component inside renderToStaticMarkup (because I have to integrate with another library) but none of the css styles are applied:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(() => ({
  backgroundColor: "red"
}));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: renderToStaticMarkup(<StyledButton>Test</StyledButton>)
      }}
    />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bouman-d1mogi?file=/index.js:0-527

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem when upgrading from React 17 to React 18. I followed provided solution:
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code

Before my code was:

```
const iconHtml = renderToStaticMarkup( 
    <Box sx={{height: 50, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}> 
      <LocationMarkerIcon color="primary" sx={{ position: "fixed", fontSize: 52 }} /> 
      <PlaceIcon kind={kind} color={color} fontSize="small" sx={{ position: "fixed" }} /> 
    </Box> 
);
```

After change my code is:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
const root = createRoot(div);                                                                                                                                                             
flushSync(() => {                                                                                                                                                                         
    root.render(                                                                                                                                                                          
        <Box sx={{height: 50, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>                                                                                          
            <LocationMarkerIcon color="primary" sx={{ position: "fixed", fontSize: 52 }} />                                                                                               
            <PlaceIcon kind={kind} color={color} fontSize="small" sx={{ position: "fixed" }} />                                                                          
        </Box>                                                                                                                                                                            
    );                                                                                                                                                                                    
});                                                                                                                                                                                       
const iconHtml = div.innerHTML;                                                                                                                                                           
div.remove();
```